# How to match each group of lines where there is no "iDontWant" in any one?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

Please understand what I want before marking it as a repeated question:

I have the following log and I want to delete all lines where it has "iDontWant" (to delete),
but not the line itself, the entire group between the dashes.
If only one row in the group has "iWant" (to delete) or anything, then it must match the whole group so I can delete it (replace with "").
In this example, these would be groups 1, 3, 4, and 5.

```
---------------------------------------------
-------------------group 1-------------------
someRandomFile.php  A:\iWant\someFolder
someRandomFile.php  A:\iWant\someFolder
someRandomFile.php  A:\iWant\someFolder
---------------------------------------------
-------------------group 2-------------------
someRandomFile.php  A:\iDontWant\someFolder
someRandomFile.php  A:\iDontWant\someFolder
---------------------------------------------
-------------------group 3-------------------
someRandomFile.xml  A:\iWant\someFolder
someRandomFile.xml  A:\iWant\someFolder
---------------------------------------------
-------------------group 4-------------------
someRandomFile.xml  A:\iDontWant\someFolder
someRandomFile.xml  A:\butWathever\someFolder
---------------------------------------------
-------------------group 5-------------------
someRandomFile.xml  A:\iWant\someFolder
someRandomFile.xml  A:\iWant\someFolder
---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
```

I made this expression that works close to this:

`(---+)(\r\n^((?!iDontWant).)*$){2,}?\r\n(---+)`

In the above regex, it matches a line that contains ---, then twice or more: breakline with anything that doesn't have "iDontWant". Then Breakline at the end to find more traces. ---

But it doesn't match group 4. And I want to match group 4 because it does not have "iDontWant" (to delete) in all lines.

### PS has repeated dashes to not jump depending on the expression used.

### Ignore the group titles.

Comment: Instead of `(?!iDontWant)`, you need `(?!\biDontWant\b)` or `(?!\\iDontWant\\)`. The former will ignore both `"..\iDontWant\.."` and `"..\foo iDontWant bar\.."` while the latter will only ignore `"..\iDontWant\.."`.

Comment: Now that you edited the input sample, your original pattern _already_ matches group 4. So, I'm not sure what the problem is at this point.

Comment: I was just correcting the expression. That doesn't get the 4. You are rushed.

Comment: I am not rushed. I answered based on the sample input that you provided. You edited it twice. After the first edit, your original pattern already matches group 4. Then, you edited it again adding "iDontWant" in group 4 but didn't explain _why_ you expect group 4 to be matched. At this point, the question is unclear.

Comment: The original didn't catch the 4. I just fixed the expression "iDontWanted". But the switch was unfortunate so I just left "iDontWant".

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Group 4 now contains "iDontWant", so why do you want to match it?

Comment: I want to delete the group 4 because it does not have "iDontWant" in all lines.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: While it's certainly _possible_ to do this with a regex, it would be much simpler to write a trivial Awk script or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove the entire group starting from the "---" line and ending before the following "---" line, you may use something like this:

```
^---+\r?\n---+[\w ]+---+(?!(?:\r?\n.*iDontWant.*$)+\r?\n---)(?:\r?\n.*$)+?(?=\r?\n---+$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/grIWHw/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^---+\r?\n` - Match a line consisting of three or more hyphens.
- `---+[\w ]+---+` - Match three or more hyphens, one or more words, three or more hyphens.
- `(?!` - Start of a negative Lookahead (make sure the following doesn't exist).

  - `(?:\r?\n.*iDontWant.*$)+` - One or more lines containing "iDontWant".
  - `\r?\n---` - Followed by a line that starts with three hyphens.
- `)` - Close the Lookahead.
- `(?:\r?\n.*$)+?` - Match one or more lines (lazy).
- `(?=\r?\n---+$)` - Followed by a line that consists of three or more hyphens.

If it's only one "---" line before each group (without "group x"), the pattern can be adjusted to:

```
^---+(?!(?:\r?\n.*iDontWant.*$)+\r?\n---+$)(?:\r?\n.*$)+?(?=\r?\n---+$|\Z)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rUjlYb/1)**.

Comment: Thx, it works nice. But why it does not match the dashes below the match? I think you are trying to match it too.. But it is not important now ;)

Comment: @Cristiano The dashes lines are either part of the following group or part of the preceding group. Based on your sample input, it seems like the former is correct and that's why it only matches the preceding dashes lines. If you want to match the following lines as well, you could replace the final Lookahead with what's inside of it.

Comment: The original log does not have "group n" title between the dashes. But I am unable to adjust your code. Can you fix it with no "---group n---" version?

Comment: So, each group is followed by two dashes lines? Only one dashes line? Please be specific so that I can modify the pattern accordingly. It's probably better if you can provide a sample of your _actual_ log (you may use regex101, pastebin, or whatever).

Comment: Well, in truth there is just one dashed line between the groups. I just duplicated it because in some regex it jump groups.  But there should be nothing written "group N" between the lines. I inserted titles to illustrate... I tried this and it's satisfactory:  ` ^---+$\r?\n---+(?!(?:\r?\n.*iDontWant.*$)+\r?\n---)(?:\r?\n.*$)+?(?=\r?\n---+$) `

Comment: @Cristiano Actually, in that case, you don't need the first `---+$\r?\n` part. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me know if this short code is what you wanted to match your undesired lines?

Find: `^\w+.*?\\(?:idontwant.*)`

```
 `Or` may be this
```

Find: `^(?!.*iwant).*`